# CentOS Install - Starting a Kickstart

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, kickstart

I have a kickstart file hosted. Let's say it is hosted at http://example.com/ks/ks.cfg

I booted the CentOS 6.2 media and hit tab. Before editing anything this shows:

```
vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img
```

I have been reading online and I found that I should replace that with this:

```
linux ks=http://example.com/ks/ks.cfg
```

I have two questions about this:

1) Once I hit enter, it is suppose to save, right? If I hit tab again it appears to be back to the original "vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img". Why isn't it saving?

2) I am considering using a disk or floppy instead to hold the kickstart. If I am to continue with the hosted kickstart file, how can I configure the network before the install to ensure that the server can access the kickstart file to install?

Sorry if any of these questions are amateurish!

Answer (score 6):

With EL6, all you need to type is `ks=http://example.com/ks/ks.cfg`. You don't need `linux` anymore.

As for network configuration, you can enter [some basic network parameters](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda_Boot_Options) at the same prompt... Most people prefer DHCP, the default... but something like this also works... Append this to the boot line:

`ks=http://example.com/ks/ks.cfg ip=192.168.10.17 netmask=255.255.255.0 dns=192.168.10.22 gateway=192.168.10.1 ksdev=eth0`

*Note* - Be sure to make sure that there's no problem reaching the kickstart URL from the server's network (web filters/firewalls/etc.)

Hit `TAB` to enter the boot menu.
[image]

Append the kickstart configuration information after `initrd.img`.
[image]

Hit `Enter` to start booting.

[image]

If you don't specify `ksdevice=`, you'll be prompted for an interface to load kickstart data from.
[image]

Comment: I click "Tab" to edit the boot option, type this in, and hit enter. Then, to choose the option, I hit enter again. However, it proceeds as normal, without the kickstart. Would you know why?

Comment: Browse to the kickstart URL to make sure it actually works. I'm assuming you made a kickstart file, uploaded it to a web-accessible host and can see it from the server's network.

Comment: Yes, I made sure that the kickstart file is available and accessible. So, if it isn't working, this means the server is not able to access the kickstart file?

Comment: Just as a note. Just now, I rebooted to the media and I hit Tab and enter the whole ks= along with all the IP info. I then hit enter. I hit Tab again and it seems like what I entered did not save. Could this be a possibility?

Comment: See my updated post.

Comment: @steve Did this resolve your issue?